# How can I change the language of the calendar without changing other locales

Tags: language-support, calendar

I want to change the language of the calendar to english, but when I do that through system settings/language/region formats ALL the settings change to the chosen region, including currency, timezone and date format....

How can I change ONLY the LANGUAGE of the calendar without amending any other locales?

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: not so duplicate

Answer (score 0):

`LC_TIME` is the entry regarding how the time is viewed in your system. So if you want to change **permanently** your time locale from english, to let's say, italian, all you have to do is the following:

```
sudo update-locale LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8
```

if an error show up like `*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings`, this means that you don't have that specific locale into your system and you have to generate it with the following command (this one is for french language):

```
sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8
```

after that, repeat the first command

All you have to do now is to log-out and log-in again

---

If you're unclear of which locale to use, by doing `cat /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` will list you all available supported locales onto your system

Cheers!

Comment: Nope. Changes in `/etc/default/locale` are overridden by the settings in `~/.pam_environment`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to edit the `~/.profile` file in your home directory, and add this line:

```
export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
```

That should make the month and weekday names in the calendar be displayed in English next time you log in.

It may also change the date and time format in other applications. Depending on you preferences (you didn't say where you live), you may prefer some other English locale. The one I suggested tries to comply with ISO 8601.